# Reading dat file with two delimiters using R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a data sample such as below:

> 1344428:-1,1,-1,415,-649,0.00;-1,2,-1,1090,-2167,0.00;-1,3,-1,-881,-3164,0.00;-1,4,-1,-624,1529,0.00;-1,5,-1,-849,-2875,0.00;-1,6,-1,856,-2341,0.00;-1,7,-1,758,-2408,0.00;-1,8,-1,-201,-2307,0.00;-1,9,-1,-963,-2807,0.00;-1,10,-1,-460,-3309,0.00;-1,11,-1,-1645,-1773,0.00;-1,12,-1,1487,-518,0.00;-1,13,-1,685,-3113,0.00;-1,14,-1,-935,-3217,0.00;-1,15,-1,-1101,-2430,0.00;-1,16,-1,754,-2946,0.00;-1,17,-1,823,-2497,0.00;-1,18,-1,-948,-2431,0.00;-1,19,-1,774,-2242,0.00;-1,20,-1,861,-2192,0.00;-1,21,-1,433,-3391,0.00;-1,22,-1,133,-2190,0.00;-1,23,-1,-977,-2585,0.00;-1,24,-1,-968,-2107,0.00;-1,25,-1,175,-3062,0.00;-1,26,-1,265,-2736,0.00;-1,27,-1,67,-2735,0.00;-1,28,-1,-281,-2752,0.00;4,29,-1,5550,4400,0.00;:174,-2563,11,28.67,A,Dead,SetAway;:
>   1344429:-1,1,-1,415,-649,0.00;-1,2,-1,1090,-2167,0.00;-1,3,-1,-885,-3169,0.00;-1,4,-1,-626,1527,0.00;-1,5,-1,-852,-2887,0.00;-1,6,-1,854,-2340,0.00;-1,7,-1,761,-2411,0.00;-1,8,-1,-201,-2307,0.00;-1,9,-1,-967,-2808,0.00;-1,10,-1,-460,-3309,0.00;-1,11,-1,-1647,-1777,0.00;-1,12,-1,1485,-518,0.00;-1,13,-1,687,-3118,0.00;-1,14,-1,-938,-3222,0.00;-1,15,-1,-1100,-2430,0.00;-1,16,-1,744,-2946,0.00;-1,17,-1,815,-2505,0.00;-1,18,-1,-950,-2429,0.00;-1,19,-1,773,-2237,0.00;-1,20,-1,861,-2190,0.00;-1,21,-1,433,-3392,0.00;-1,22,-1,133,-2189,0.00;-1,23,-1,-980,-2593,0.00;-1,24,-1,-961,-2109,0.00;-1,25,-1,176,-3056,0.00;-1,26,-1,265,-2731,0.00;-1,27,-1,67,-2736,0.00;-1,28,-1,-283,-2746,0.00;4,29,-1,5550,4400,0.00;:174,-2563,11,28.67,A,Dead,SetAway;:

The data is separated to 3 chunks:

1. The first is a time stamp ending with ":" we can keep this as numerical
2. then multiple sets of numbers (multiple of six) ending with ";:"
3. finally a third chunk (7 elements, mixed between string and numerical) ending with ";:"

Is there an elegant way to read this data into R data frame? I tried

```
read.table("855360.dat",
                        header = FALSE,
                            sep = ";")
```

but it requires a lot of manipulation to set the elements into the 3 chunks that I can them join and manipulate?

Comment: What's the final product you want out of this? Does everything just go on one row?

Comment: 3 lists would be fine.

Comment: Three vectors of what? Three vectors for each row? That's not a very "tabular" format so it wouldn't be a good fit for a data.frame. Do you want a list of lists or something?

Comment: yes, a list of the 3 lists. first list, for the time stamp, second list of the 7 elements in the end, third list that contains all the numbers in between. 

either that or one raw would be fine and I can take it from there.

Comment: I don't think a single-pass solution is easy here. A multi-pass may be easier, starting with `strsplit(txt, ";:")`, realizing that "even" indices are paired with their preceding odd indices. Then your question becomes two much smaller ones, looking at one "row" (timestamp-related pair): (1) how to separate out the timestamp (perhaps `strsplit(y, ":")[[1]][1]`; and (2) how to smartly extract the rows and columns from the rest of the string (perhaps `read.csv(gsub(";", "\n", z))`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a single data frame result is OK then just replace colon and semicolon with comma and read it in:

```
L <- readLines("myfile")
read.table(text =  gsub("[:;]+", ",", L), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

or if you want to generate a nested list structure then using `L` from above:

```
lapply(lapply(strsplit(L, ":"), strsplit, ";"), lapply, strsplit, ",")
```

Comment: Thank you G Grothendieck. This is indeed waht I asked for. I might mention that the first approach takes a lot of time and requires a completely uniform tabular data. Testing with 50k lines took over 189 seconds! Not the case for the second approach or the method used in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is turned into a multi-pass process, it may take a little longer but may be simpler to modify and maintain in the long run.

If you start by splitting the string by the `";:"` characters, you'll notice that the odd-indices are the main data (including timestamp), and the even-indices are your "third chunk" with mixed num/char entries. Once you break this down, you may realize that we still have a parsing problem, but it's a little simpler.

```
txt <- "1344428:-1,1,-1,415,-649,0.00;-1,2,-1,1090,-2167,0.00;-1,3,-1,-881,-3164,0.00;-1,4,-1,-624,1529,0.00;-1,5,-1,-849,-2875,0.00;-1,6,-1,856,-2341,0.00;-1,7,-1,758,-2408,0.00;-1,8,-1,-201,-2307,0.00;-1,9,-1,-963,-2807,0.00;-1,10,-1,-460,-3309,0.00;-1,11,-1,-1645,-1773,0.00;-1,12,-1,1487,-518,0.00;-1,13,-1,685,-3113,0.00;-1,14,-1,-935,-3217,0.00;-1,15,-1,-1101,-2430,0.00;-1,16,-1,754,-2946,0.00;-1,17,-1,823,-2497,0.00;-1,18,-1,-948,-2431,0.00;-1,19,-1,774,-2242,0.00;-1,20,-1,861,-2192,0.00;-1,21,-1,433,-3391,0.00;-1,22,-1,133,-2190,0.00;-1,23,-1,-977,-2585,0.00;-1,24,-1,-968,-2107,0.00;-1,25,-1,175,-3062,0.00;-1,26,-1,265,-2736,0.00;-1,27,-1,67,-2735,0.00;-1,28,-1,-281,-2752,0.00;4,29,-1,5550,4400,0.00;:174,-2563,11,28.67,A,Dead,SetAway;: 1344429:-1,1,-1,415,-649,0.00;-1,2,-1,1090,-2167,0.00;-1,3,-1,-885,-3169,0.00;-1,4,-1,-626,1527,0.00;-1,5,-1,-852,-2887,0.00;-1,6,-1,854,-2340,0.00;-1,7,-1,761,-2411,0.00;-1,8,-1,-201,-2307,0.00;-1,9,-1,-967,-2808,0.00;-1,10,-1,-460,-3309,0.00;-1,11,-1,-1647,-1777,0.00;-1,12,-1,1485,-518,0.00;-1,13,-1,687,-3118,0.00;-1,14,-1,-938,-3222,0.00;-1,15,-1,-1100,-2430,0.00;-1,16,-1,744,-2946,0.00;-1,17,-1,815,-2505,0.00;-1,18,-1,-950,-2429,0.00;-1,19,-1,773,-2237,0.00;-1,20,-1,861,-2190,0.00;-1,21,-1,433,-3392,0.00;-1,22,-1,133,-2189,0.00;-1,23,-1,-980,-2593,0.00;-1,24,-1,-961,-2109,0.00;-1,25,-1,176,-3056,0.00;-1,26,-1,265,-2731,0.00;-1,27,-1,67,-2736,0.00;-1,28,-1,-283,-2746,0.00;4,29,-1,5550,4400,0.00;:174,-2563,11,28.67,A,Dead,SetAway;:"

x <- strsplit(txt, ";:")[[1]]
x <- sapply(x, trimws, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
x[1]
# [1] "1344428:-1,1,-1,415,-649,0.00;-1,2,-1,1090,-2167,0.00;-1,3,-1,-881,-3164,0.00;-1,4,-1,-624,1529,0.00;-1,5,-1,-849,-2875,0.00;-1,6,-1,856,-2341,0.00;-1,7,-1,758,-2408,0.00;-1,8,-1,-201,-2307,0.00;-1,9,-1,-963,-2807,0.00;-1,10,-1,-460,-3309,0.00;-1,11,-1,-1645,-1773,0.00;-1,12,-1,1487,-518,0.00;-1,13,-1,685,-3113,0.00;-1,14,-1,-935,-3217,0.00;-1,15,-1,-1101,-2430,0.00;-1,16,-1,754,-2946,0.00;-1,17,-1,823,-2497,0.00;-1,18,-1,-948,-2431,0.00;-1,19,-1,774,-2242,0.00;-1,20,-1,861,-2192,0.00;-1,21,-1,433,-3391,0.00;-1,22,-1,133,-2190,0.00;-1,23,-1,-977,-2585,0.00;-1,24,-1,-968,-2107,0.00;-1,25,-1,175,-3062,0.00;-1,26,-1,265,-2736,0.00;-1,27,-1,67,-2735,0.00;-1,28,-1,-281,-2752,0.00;4,29,-1,5550,4400,0.00"
x[2]
# [1] "174,-2563,11,28.67,A,Dead,SetAway"
```

An important assumption here is that we will always have pairs of timestamp/data and follow-on chunks:

```
if (length(x) %% 2 != 0) stop("oops, uneven pairs")
odds <- seq(1, length(x), by = 2)
str(x[odds])
#  chr [1:2] "1344428:-1,1,-1,415,-649,0.00;-1,2,-1,1090,-2167,0.00;-1,3,-1,-881,-3164,0.00;-1,4,-1,-624,1529,0.00;-1,5,-1,-849,-2875,0.00;-1"| __truncated__ ...
x[-odds]
# [1] "174,-2563,11,28.67,A,Dead,SetAway" "174,-2563,11,28.67,A,Dead,SetAway"
```

From here, realize that we can easily extract the timestamp with another `strsplit`, and then the rest can be converted into something `read.csv` likes by replacing `";"` with newlines (same with your third-chunk):

```
timestamps <- lapply(firstsplit, function(z) data.frame(timestamp = as.numeric(z[1])))
data1 <- lapply(firstsplit, function(lst) read.csv(textConnection(gsub(";", "\n", lst[[2]])), header = FALSE))
data2 <- lapply(secondsplit, function(z) read.csv(textConnection(z), header = FALSE))
```

Taking a peek at one of the pairs of data:

```
bothlst <- mapply(list, timestamps, data1, data2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
str(bothlst[[1]])
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ timestamp: num 1344428
#  $ :'data.frame': 29 obs. of  6 variables:
#   ..$ V1: int [1:29] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
#   ..$ V2: int [1:29] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   ..$ V3: int [1:29] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
#   ..$ V4: int [1:29] 415 1090 -881 -624 -849 856 758 -201 -963 -460 ...
#   ..$ V5: int [1:29] -649 -2167 -3164 1529 -2875 -2341 -2408 -2307 -2807 -3309 ...
#   ..$ V6: num [1:29] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  7 variables:
#   ..$ V1: int 174
#   ..$ V2: int -2563
#   ..$ V3: int 11
#   ..$ V4: num 28.7
#   ..$ V5: Factor w/ 1 level "A": 1
#   ..$ V6: Factor w/ 1 level "Dead": 1
#   ..$ V7: Factor w/ 1 level "SetAway": 1
```

This is a nice nested-list depiction of your data. I intentionally made the `timestamp` a `data.frame` to simplify a step later, though this is certainly not a requirement.

If you want this depicted in a single `data.frame` with all data, there are two things to keep in mind:

1. Your `timestamp` and "third-chunk data" will be repeated across all rows within the data. This may not be a problem depending on how you intend to use the data. **This method breaks** if the assumption of a single row of data in the "third-chunk" is invalid.
2. We have the same column names in both of the two data elements. This is a problem that is easily avoided if you have pre-defined columns (always 6 and 7 columns) or if the columns are defined in the data (they are not in your example). If neither of those work, then you need to decide on a naming convention that works for you. For the sake of this example, I will change the second `data.frame` from `V1` naming to `X1` naming.

With number 2 in mind:

```
data2mod <- lapply(data2, function(df) setNames(df, paste("X", seq_along(df), sep = "")))
bothlst2 <- mapply(list, timestamps, data1, data2mod, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Now, for each element, we can "column-bind" the elements into a single `data.frame`:

```
# bothdf <- lapply(bothlst2, cbind.data.frame)
str(bothdf)
# List of 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 29 obs. of  14 variables:
#   ..$ timestamp: num [1:29] 1344428 1344428 1344428 1344428 1344428 ...
#   ..$ V1       : int [1:29] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
#   ..$ V2       : int [1:29] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   ..$ V3       : int [1:29] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
#   ..$ V4       : int [1:29] 415 1090 -881 -624 -849 856 758 -201 -963 -460 ...
#   ..$ V5       : int [1:29] -649 -2167 -3164 1529 -2875 -2341 -2408 -2307 -2807 -3309 ...
#   ..$ V6       : num [1:29] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ X1       : int [1:29] 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 ...
#   ..$ X2       : int [1:29] -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 ...
#   ..$ X3       : int [1:29] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
#   ..$ X4       : num [1:29] 28.7 28.7 28.7 28.7 28.7 ...
#   ..$ X5       : Factor w/ 1 level "A": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#   ..$ X6       : Factor w/ 1 level "Dead": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#   ..$ X7       : Factor w/ 1 level "SetAway": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ :'data.frame': 29 obs. of  14 variables:
#   ..$ timestamp: num [1:29] 1344429 1344429 1344429 1344429 1344429 ...
#   ..$ V1       : int [1:29] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
#   ..$ V2       : int [1:29] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   ..$ V3       : int [1:29] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
#   ..$ V4       : int [1:29] 415 1090 -885 -626 -852 854 761 -201 -967 -460 ...
#   ..$ V5       : int [1:29] -649 -2167 -3169 1527 -2887 -2340 -2411 -2307 -2808 -3309 ...
#   ..$ V6       : num [1:29] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ X1       : int [1:29] 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 ...
#   ..$ X2       : int [1:29] -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 -2563 ...
#   ..$ X3       : int [1:29] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
#   ..$ X4       : num [1:29] 28.7 28.7 28.7 28.7 28.7 ...
#   ..$ X5       : Factor w/ 1 level "A": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#   ..$ X6       : Factor w/ 1 level "Dead": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#   ..$ X7       : Factor w/ 1 level "SetAway": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

From here it's rather straight-forward to deal with them independently, or to combine them in a similar fashion:

```
head(do.call("rbind", bothdf))
#   timestamp V1 V2 V3   V4    V5 V6  X1    X2 X3    X4 X5   X6      X7
# 1   1344428 -1  1 -1  415  -649  0 174 -2563 11 28.67  A Dead SetAway
# 2   1344428 -1  2 -1 1090 -2167  0 174 -2563 11 28.67  A Dead SetAway
# 3   1344428 -1  3 -1 -881 -3164  0 174 -2563 11 28.67  A Dead SetAway
# 4   1344428 -1  4 -1 -624  1529  0 174 -2563 11 28.67  A Dead SetAway
# 5   1344428 -1  5 -1 -849 -2875  0 174 -2563 11 28.67  A Dead SetAway
# 6   1344428 -1  6 -1  856 -2341  0 174 -2563 11 28.67  A Dead SetAway
```

Based on my first bullet above, you'll notice that the `timestamp` column and all `X*` columns are redundant, similar to a join of tables.